# How to get Git diff similar to that immediately after manual resolve conflict?

Tags: git, merge, diff

I have been using Git for a long time, sometimes it is necessary to resolve conflicts manually.

When the merge is stopped because of a merge failure, I resolve the conflict manually. At this moment I can call `git diff` and it shows me only those differences, that were conflicted and resolved manually by myself.

But after the merge commit, it looks like I have no way to see such a diff again. The most similar is the three-way diff which shows all changes made from both branches, no matter, whether they were conflicted and resolved manually, or merged automatically.

Did somebody find some trick to see such a diff - made immediately before the merge commit, - again?

Below is the test case demonstrating my question in action.

The file `test-git-merge.sh` to be executed in bash or sh from the empty directory created for the test:

```bash
#/bin/sh

git init
git config user.email "nnseva@gmail.com"
git config user.name "Vsevolod Novikov"
echo a1>>a.txt
echo a2>>a.txt
echo a3>>a.txt
echo b1>>b.txt
echo b2>>b.txt
echo b3>>b.txt
git add a.txt b.txt
git commit -a -m "Initial"
git checkout -b branch-x
echo a1>a.txt
echo "branch-x" >>a.txt
echo a2>>a.txt
echo a3>>a.txt
echo "branch-x" >>b.txt
git commit -a -m "Branch X"
git checkout master
git checkout -b branch-y
echo "branch-y" >>d.txt
git add d.txt
echo a1>a.txt
echo a2>>a.txt
echo "branch-y" >>a.txt
echo a3>>a.txt
echo "branch-y" >>b.txt
git commit -a -m "Branch Y"
git checkout branch-x
git checkout -b branch-z
git merge branch-y
echo "------------- Diff after merge conflict --------------"
git diff
echo b1>b.txt
echo b2>>b.txt
echo b3>>b.txt
echo "branch-x" >>b.txt
echo "branch-y" >>b.txt
echo "------------- Diff after merge conflict resolve --------------"
git diff
git commit -a -m "Fixed merge"
echo "------------- DIff for merge commit --------------"
git diff HEAD HEAD^@
```

------------- Diff after merge conflict resolve --------------

```
diff --cc b.txt
index dac91e4,22e151d..0000000
--- a/b.txt
+++ b/b.txt
@@@ -1,4 -1,4 +1,5 @@@
  b1
  b2
  b3
 +branch-x
+ branch-y
```

------------- DIff for merge commit --------------

```
diff --cc a.txt
index 45f2c54,dd210a3..4164b20
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@@ -1,4 -1,4 +1,5 @@@
  a1
 +branch-x
  a2
+ branch-y
  a3
diff --cc b.txt
index dac91e4,22e151d..7aaeeec
--- a/b.txt
+++ b/b.txt
@@@ -1,4 -1,4 +1,5 @@@
  b1
  b2
  b3
 +branch-x
+ branch-y
```

As you can see, the latter diff has an **extra** not necessary section for the `a.txt` file, which was resolved automatically.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of `Diff after merge conflict resolve`, `a.txt` is staged while `b.txt` is not. So, `git diff` outputs only the diff of `b.txt`.

In order to output only the diff of `b.txt`, we need to append `b.txt` to `git diff HEAD HEAD^@`.

```
git diff HEAD HEAD^@ -- b.txt
```

But it's not smart to manually specify `b.txt`. We can find out the files that have conflicts during the merge.

```
git show HEAD --pretty= --remerge-diff --name-only
```

And put them together.

```
git diff HEAD HEAD^@ -- $(git show HEAD --pretty= --remerge-diff --name-only)
```

Comment: your advice is fine, except that my current version of the git installed on the Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS was 2.34.1, and the key `--remerge-diff` has been initially introduced in the [v.2.36.0](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show/2.36.0) - compare to [v.2.35.0](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show/2.35.0)

In order to use the last version of the GIT package we can follow recommendations on the GIT Download page for [Linux](https://git-scm.com/download/linux) or [other platforms](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

After the GIT upgrade to tle last version, your advise works, thank you!